# Python Pandas Dataframe Remove Float Trailing Zeros

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that I'm outputting to csv. I would like to keep the data types (i.e. not convert everything to string). I need to format the date properly and there are other non-float columns.

How do I remove trailing zeros from the floats while not changing datatypes? This is what I've tried:

```
pd.DataFrame(myDataFrame).to_csv("MyOutput.csv", index=False, date_format='%m/%d/%Y', float_format="%.8f")
```

For example, this:

```
09/26/2022,43.27334000,2,111.37000000
09/24/2022,16.25930000,5,73.53000000
```

Should be this:

```
09/26/2022,43.27334,2,111.37
09/24/2022,16.2593,5,73.53
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you print the DataFrame and show what it looks like before you save it?

Answer (score 0):

You can load your code like this, without the `float_format`. Also, if the `myDataFrame` variable is already a dataframe object, you don't need to add the `pd.DataFrame` part, you can just do the following.

```
myDataFrame.to_csv("MyOutput.csv", index=False, date_format='%m/%d/%Y')
```